# Multi-indexing with tuples

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, multi-index

I have a multi-dimensional `np.array`. I know the shape of the first N dimension and of the last M dimensions. E.g.,

```py
>>> n = (3,4,5)
>>> m = (6,)
>>> a = np.ones(n + m)
>>> a.shape
(3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Using tuples as indices allows for quick indexing like of the first N dimensions, like

```py
>>> i = (1,1,2)
>>> a[i].shape
(6,)
```

Using list does not give me the same result I need

```py
>>> i = [1,1,2]
>>> a[i].shape
(3, 4, 5, 6)
```

But I am having trouble doing multi-indexing (both to retrieve / assign values). For example,

```py
>>> i = (1,1,2)
>>> j = (2,2,2)
```

I need to pass something like

```py
>>> a[[i, j]]
```

and get an output shape of `(2, 6)`.

Instead I get

```py
>>> a[[i, j]].shape
(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

or

```py
>>> a[(i, j)].shape
(3, 5, 6)
```

I can always loop or change how I index things (like using `np.reshape` and `np.unravel_index`), but is there a more pythonic way to achieve what I need?

**EDIT**
I'd need this for any number of indices, e.g.,

```py
>>> i = (1,1,2)
>>> j = (2,2,2)
>>> k = (0,0,0)
...
```

Comment: You have to provide the indices for each dimension separately! For instance: `a[ [1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2] ]`. A quick way to do that is via `a[tuple(zip(i, j))]`. More info here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing

Comment: Nice! I tried to `zip` but forgot to add `tuple` again :P
If you write an answer I'd be happy to accept it :)

Comment: I believe in Python 2.7, indexing with `zip` worked without `tuple`.

Comment: @Jason: In 2.7, `zip` returned a `list` of `tuple`s, which would behave differently than a `tuple` of `tuple`s with `numpy` indexing, so the conversion to `tuple` would still be required to achieve the intended semantics.

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs: Ooh, that's better than my solution. I'd upvote if you posted it (I don't want to just steal it for my answer).

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs: It can be abbreviated a bit thanks to unpacking with just `a[*zip(i, j)]` (the unpacking produces a `tuple` in the context of indexing).

Comment: You're right! But that's a python 3.10 or 3.11+ feature :)

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs: Huh, it is more recent than the rest of the PEP 448 features. TIL. I don't use `numpy` much, so I hadn't realized it was so recent.

Comment: Btw, I have to work with any number of indices, so I have to do (see edits): `indices = [i, j, k]`, `a[tuple(zip(*indices))]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a list of indices:

```
idx = [
    (1, 1, 2),  # Your i
    (2, 2, 2),  # Your j
    (0, 0, 0),  # Your k
    (1, 2, 1),  # ... 
    (2, 0, 1),  # extend as necessary
]
```

and your array `a` with shape `(3, 4, 5, 6)`.

When you write `out = a[idx]`, numpy interprets it like this:

```
out = np.array([
    [a[1], a[1], a[2]],
    [a[2], a[2], a[2]],
    [a[0], a[0], a[0]],
    [a[1], a[2], a[1]],
    [a[2], a[0], a[1]],
])
```

In which, e.g. `a[0]`, is just the first subarray of `a`, thus with shape `(4, 5, 6)`!

As a result, you're left with what represents an array of shape `(5, 3)` (the shape of the index), containing `(4, 5, 6)` subarrays of `a`! (... final result being `(5, 3, 4, 5, 6)`, or `np.shape(idx) + a.shape[1:]`).

---

Instead what you want is the following:

```
out = np.array([
    a[1, 1, 2],
    a[2, 2, 2],
    a[0, 0, 0],
    a[1, 2, 1],
    a[2, 0, 1],
])
```

The way to accomplish it "vectorially" in numpy is the following:

```
out = a[
    [1, 2, 0, 1, 2],  # [idx[0][0], idx[1][0], idx[2][0], ...]
    [1, 2, 0, 2, 0],  # [idx[0][1], idx[1][1], idx[2][1], ...]
    [2, 2, 0, 1, 1]   # [idx[0][2], idx[1][2], idx[2][2], ...]
]
```

That behavior is documented in the [indexing guide](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing):

> Advanced indices always are broadcast and iterated as one:
>
> ```
> result[i_1, ..., i_M] == x[ind_1[i_1, ..., i_M], ind_2[i_1, ..., i_M],
>                            ..., ind_N[i_1, ..., i_M]]
> ```

To transform the original `idx` into such an indexer, you can use the `tuple(zip(*idx))` trick.

Numpy's indexing system is magically flexible, but the cost of that flexibility is that these kinds of "simple" tasks become unintuitive... at least in my opinion ;)

Answer (score 1):

Extract each selection, then stitch them back together into a new array?

```
>>> np.array([a[i], a[j]]).shape
(2, 6)
```

Comment: Thanks! I have edited my question btw, I need to work with an arbitrary number of indices. Your solution still works: `indices = [i, j, k]`, `np.array([a[i] for i in indices])`.

Answer (score 1):

I tested both ShadowRanger's and Chrysophylaxs' solutions, comparing them with my original ravel solution. I timed them and Chrysophylaxs' is the fastest.

```py
import time
import numpy as np

n = (3, 4, 5)
m = (2, 4, 6)
a = np.random.rand(*(n + m))

indices = [tuple(np.random.randint(n)) for _ in range(100)]

test = 100000

t1 = time.time()

for _ in range(test):
  x = a[tuple(zip(*indices))]  

t2 = time.time()

for _ in range(test):
  y = np.array([a[i] for i in indices])

t3 = time.time()

for _ in range(test):
  b = a.reshape(np.prod(n), np.prod(m))
  j = [np.ravel_multi_index(i, n) for i in indices]
  z = b[j].reshape(-1, *m)

t4 = time.time()
```

```py
>>> print(t2 - t1, t3 - t2, t4 - t3)
>>> print(x.shape, y.shape, z.shape)
>>> assert(np.all(x - y == 0))
>>> assert(np.all(x - z == 0))
3.8938186168670654 4.831823110580444 37.469303131103516
(100, 2, 4, 6) (100, 2, 4, 6) (100, 2, 4, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's be pedantic, to clarify what's happening in each case.

```
In [19]: >>> n = (3,4,5)
    ...: >>> m = (6,)
```

Plus on tuples (and lists and strings) joins them:

```
In [20]: n+m
Out[20]: (3, 4, 5, 6)

In [21]: a=np.ones(n+m)
```

Indexing with a tuple is the same as entering each scalar alone.  It's the comma that makes the tuple,not the ().  Actually it's interpreter that passes the tuple to the object; it's objects own `getitem` method that interprets it.  (Lists complain if you give them a tuple, but arrays like it :) ).

```
In [22]: a[1,1,2].shape
Out[22]: (6,)
```

There's an automatic trailing slice.  In the following I'll include that to be clear(er):

```
In [23]: a[1,1,2,:].shape
Out[23]: (6,)

In [24]: >>> i = (1,1,2)
    ...: >>> j = (2,2,2)
```

`[i,j]` gets converted to an array, (2,3) shape:

```
In [25]: np.array([i,j])
Out[25]: 
array([[1, 1, 2],
       [2, 2, 2]])
```

So that array is used to index just the first dimension. The rest are traling.

```
In [26]: a[np.array([i,j]),:,:,:].shape
Out[26]: (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

A tuple of tuples:

```
In [27]: (i,j)
Out[27]: ((1, 1, 2), (2, 2, 2))
```

The inner tuples are converted to lists, or rather to arrays.  So the 2 indices broadcast together, selecting a (3,) shape (think of that as a "diagonal")

```
In [29]: a[[1,1,2],[2,2,2],:,:].shape
Out[29]: (3, 5, 6)
```

Adding in a `k`, `a[i,j,k]` would give a (3,6) shape.

I don't know how your `i,j` is supposed to produce a (2,6) shape

Wait, maybe it's the equivalent of

```
In [32]: np.stack([a[i],a[j]]).shape
Out[32]: (2, 6)
```

Or equivalently joining the 2 selections with `np.array`.

Just as experiement, here's an equivalent:

```
In [45]: b=np.arange(3*4*5*6).reshape(a.shape)

In [46]: c=np.stack([b[i],b[j]])
In [47]: d=b[[1,2],[1,2],[2,2]]
In [48]: np.allclose(c,d)
Out[48]: True
```

So we need to convert the `i,j` tuples into this tuple of pairs.

```
In [55]: tuple([[i1,j1] for i1,j1 in zip(i,j)])
Out[55]: ([1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2])
In [56]: tuple(np.array([i,j]).T.tolist())
Out[56]: ([1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2])
In [57]: tuple(np.stack([i,j],1).tolist())
Out[57]: ([1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2])
```

and with a third tuple

```
In [58]: k=(0,0,0)    
In [59]: tuple(np.stack([i,j,k],1).tolist())
Out[59]: ([1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0], [2, 2, 0])
```

we don't need the `tolist`, though it's pretty fast:

```
In [61]: b[tuple(np.stack([i,j,k],1))]
Out[61]: 
array([[162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167],
       [312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317],
       [  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5]])
```

Comment: Using `()` makes it more readable to me and it's what popular formats (like Black) use. If I write `m = 6,` it's very easy (to me, at least) to miss the `,` and think it's a scalar :)

Comment: Interestingly, I'm not sure if the commas make the tuple for the `i, j, k` inside `a[i, j, k]`; since one of `i`, `j`, or `k` could be a slice written in `:` form...